# Form not working when updating appointment status

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, isset

Update status not working but when I try to put my code in to else it's working what is wrong with isset? did I something wrong? Please check my code below thank you in advance

```
            <?php 
                    if (isset($_POST["marked_as_completed"])) 
                    {
                    $appointment = new WC_Appointment( $appointment_id );
                    $appointment->update_status('cancelled', 'order_note');
                    } 
            ?>
```

```html
<form method="post" name="update_status">
  <button class="cancelappointment" type="submit" name="marked_as_completed">Mark as Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST) and see what coming. I think you are not calling any action on the form that why.

Comment: I did but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your php file

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="update_status">
  <input class="cancelappointment" type="submit" name="marked_as_completed" value="Mark as Cancel" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["marked_as_completed"])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not working php and the form is on the same page

Comment: Try now i have edited my answer. it working fine in my end on localhost. Php and form is on same page as well. If its still does not work for your. I would say that something else is wrong. Nothing to do with Php and form.

Comment: Can you accept this an answer please. So this solution will help others too.